# undefined method `delete' for 0:Fixnum Prawn/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn

I am receiving a very strange error. `` undefined method `delete' for 0:Fixnum `` when I try to style my rows. Why is this the case?

```
table(headers + Invoice.all.map do |invoice|
                [
                    make_cell(content: invoice.invoice_number),
                    make_cell(content: format_date(invoice.invoice_date)),
                    make_cell(content: format_date(invoice.due_date)),
                    make_cell(content: format_price(invoice.total)),
                    make_cell(content: format_price(invoice.fees_total)),
                    make_cell(content: format_price(invoice.actual_total))
                ]
      end, table_options, style(cell(0), padding: [4,2]))
```

Comment: could you please paste the stacktrace of your error?

Comment: I know the problem is with style(cell(0), padding: [4,2]). When I add this, the error occurs. Does this look right to you?

Comment: sure the syntax is correct? when I take the map block out its looks like `table(headers + invoices_block, table_options, style(cell(0), padding: [4,2]))`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I am still receiving the same error. I know it is due to my syntax (with the styling) but I cannot find the correct way.